# É possível criar uma estrutura de decisão em uma tabela no SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho um banco de dados massivo, possui mais de 2.000 linhas, e a segunda coluna possui um ENUM que permite apenas 'Opcao 1' e 'Opcao 2'. Se eu inserir na tabela 200 linhas e escrever o nome do ENUM errado como exemplo `insert into tabela values ('blabla', 'Ocao 2')` ele retornara uma área vazia no campo do ENUM e isso iria acarretar em uma grande dor de cabeça. Existe alguma forma no SQL de eu prevenir que isso aconteça, como uma estrutura de verificação, impedindo de eu executar o código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um `trigger` que nos eventos `UPDATE` e `INSERT` verificam se o dado na coluna ENUM é válido ou não. Caso não o seja, gere uma exceção para ser tratada na aplicação.

Outra opção, é criar uma outra tabela com os possíveis valores do ENUM, e então referncia-la na primeira através de uma chave estrangeira, assegurando através de restrições de integridade que um valor não suportado seja inserido.

Acredito que seja possível fazer isso utilizando `DOMAIN`, mas não sei se MySQL suporta isto, nem qual a extensão deste suporte.

Comment: Darei uma olhada Vinícius, obrigado pela resposta, verei como funciona esse trigger e mais tarde lhe darei o feedback

Comment: Decidi não usar mais o ENUM, tem muita gente apresentando vários pontos negativos... Mas você respondeu minha pergunta, vlw!