# O que significa este pedaço de instrução sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho esta instrução no arquivo de modelagem de banco de dados e gostaria de saber do que se trata.

```
'price_type' enum("S" "M")
```

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81801/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126301/101

Comment: sita isso para sql ficar muito sem sentido uma vez que no sql server não tem enum, se não fosse pela tag, não entenderia coisa alguma. Melhore sua pergunta e veja as relacionadas acima.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [É possível criar uma estrutura de decisão em uma tabela no SQL?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38874/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-criar-uma-estrutura-de-decis%c3%a3o-em-uma-tabela-no-sql)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trata-se de uma [enum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html).

Com uma enum você pode restringir os valores de uma coluna às opções especificadas, e.g., no seu caso `'S'` ou `'M'`.
Enum é um tipo bastante eficiente e compacto. Internamente o banco usa números para representar cada valor da `enum`. Geralmente utilizamos enum quando os valores de uma coluna pertencem à um universo bem definido e estático (i.e, você não prevê novos tipos de preço, se esse fosse o caso uma foreign key para uma tabela de domínio com os tipos de preço seria uma solução melhor).